# ¿Cuales son las consecuencias de no inicializar un apuntador en c?

Tags: c, punteros, sintaxis

¿Cuales son las consecuencias de no inicializar un apuntador en c ? Y que errores comunes se pueden encontrar cuando utilizamos apuntadores? y ¿que tan peligrosos pueden ser estos errores?

Comment: Amigo, esta pregunta suena a tarea. Te recomiendo que leas sobre [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida. Y tambien que seas especifico, solo una pregunta

Comment: Es una pregunta basada en opiniones lo que generaría su cierre.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 5):

**Consecuencias**

El peligro de un puntero no inicializado es que apunta a una posición aleatoria de la memoria. Intentar acceder y/o modificar dicha memoria puede tener efectos fatales para tu aplicación:

- Intento de lectura: El sistema operativo puede detectar que accedes a zonas de memoria que no te peretenecen y matar tu proceso. En caso contrario, no sabes qué estás leyendo, luego los algoritmos que se basen en esos valores funcionarán arbitrariamente
- Intento de escritura:

  - Si por casualidad apunta a memoria que te pertenece: acabarás modificando el estado de otras variables (no se sabe cuáles), luego tu programa se volverá errático
  - Si no apunta a memoria que te pertenezca lo normal es que el Sistema Operativo detecte el acceso a memoria y mate tu proceso para evitar que corrompas la memoria de otros procesos... si esto no sucediese el propio Sistema Operativo podría volverse inestable.

**errores comunes se pueden encontrar cuando utilizamos apuntadores**

Los punteros no son más que variables, solo que en vez de manejar valores en bruto, almacenan posiciones de memoria. Por ello sufren los mismos errores que las variables comunes:

- Punteros no inicializados
- Operaciones aritméticas incorrectas que generan valores inválidos
- ...

Adicionalmente, los punteros se usan principalmente para acceder a colecciones de datos. Así pues, un error bastante común consiste en exceder los límites de la colección:

```
int matriz[2][5];

for( int i=0; i<2; i++ )
{
    for( int j=0; j<5; j++ )
    {
        matriz[j][i] = 0;
    }
}
```

En este ejemplo alguien ha cometido el error de intercambiar los índices `i` y `j`. En consecuencia, el algoritmo acaba accediendo a posiciones que no pertenecen a la colección, como las posiciones `[3][0]` o `[4][0]`:

```
 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F 10 11 12 13 14 15
|           matriz            | otras variables .................
| fila 0       | fila 1       | fila 2 ???   | fila 3 ???   |
  ^              ^              ^              ^ 
  matriz[0][0]   matriz[1][0]   matriz[3][0]   matriz[4][0]
```

El código no hace ninguna comprobación sobre el puntero... este es libre para apuntar a donde desee, si lo mueves a una posición incorrecta nadie te avisará pero pagarás igualmente las consecuencias.

**que tan peligrosos pueden ser estos errores**

Como ya te he comentado, los errores se dividen básicamente en 2:

- El programa se *muere*, ya que el Sistema Operativo toma la decisión de terminarlo por acceder a memoria que no le pertenece
- Tu propio programa, otros programas o el Sistema Operativo se vuelven inestables

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por contestar amablemente y aclarar la duda , saludos